# Is there a way to set Test Connection to property in Azure Storage Connection using a variable?

Tags: ssis, blob, azure-storage

I'm trying to set value of Test Connection to property to Container through variables but I cant find any variable in expressions to do so.
Is it even possible to set it through variable? If yes, then which one?

Comment: Are you talking about the Azure Blob Upload task? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/data-science-process/move-data-to-azure-blob-using-ssis

Comment: Can you please edit question and  add more information what you looking for?